# php-csv-parser not working properly

Tags: php, csv

I used php-csv-parser for to parse my csv files in my site. in my csv file I have list of numbers for to store in table.

if I create the csv file in openoffice.org it works fine. in case I created the csv files using ms office it creates a problem.

in my csv file I have numbers like below,

1001
1002
1003
1004

if I give like,
1,1001
2,1002
3,1003

above also works fine when I store csv in openoffice.org.

but I created the above format in msoffice csv file it won't parse correctly.

when I print that array it shows like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1000000001
2
            [2] => 1000000002
3
            [3] => 1000000003
4
            [4] => 1000000004
5
            [5] => 1000000005
        )

)
```

it shows all the records in one array.

now I need if the csv is created in anyformat with, or normal I need to parse the values correctly.

like every data's parse as each record, not like above.

else can you please suggest me any other csv parser?.

Comment: What do you mean with "php-csv-parser"? If you mean the [PHP function `fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/function.fgetcsv.php) – it allows to specify the delimiter, which is a semicolon `;` in the case of Word-generated CSV files. BTW: "not working properly" is not a question…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the alternate CSV parser.

try this one http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/

it works great. if i create datas in notepad and saved it as a CSV. that also working fine. it parse as each row as a record even i give row values with (,). like,

1,20
2,21
3,22
4,23

it parses the file and give value as array like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 22
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 23
        )

)
```